# Open source examples of well designed applications

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, open-source

Do you know of well designed open source applications that are instructive to analyse?

Specifically, I'm interested in practical applications object-relational mapping in C++ based programs, where there is a good separation between a domain model and persistence/serialization functionality.

Comment: I'd be interested to see this too.  I'm pretty much convinced that it's impossible to actually code good OO in C++ due to lack of GC and the weight of new classes and the nature of C++ programmers to resist constant memory allocations/deallocations (new objects). Most OO programmers I know agree.

Comment: @BillK I suggest you pick up a [good book about C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C++ has RAII and you don't dynamically allocate stuff in C++ unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Not dynamically allocating stuff is the kind of thing that is the opposite of OO programming.  It's not that OO programming is impossible in C++ or anything, it's just that everything in C++ encourages you to do things in a less-OO way.  It can be overcome, but most C++ programmers seem to give up and come up with a hybrid solution that has pieces of OO but doesn't really commit.  If you do go full-OO, you might as well go with Java because your solution will probably be faster and definitely cleaner (heap allocations, the heart of OO programming, are not C++'s best attribute)

Answer (score 4):

If you include well designed open source *libraries* that are instructive to analyse, have a look at [Boost](http://www.boost.org).

About persistence / serialization (not relational mapping though), have a look at [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), you might find nice ideas!

> "...one of the most highly regarded and expertly designed C++ library projects in the world."
>       — Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu, C++ Coding Standards
>
> "Item 55: Familiarize yourself with Boost."
>       — Scott Meyers, Effective C++, 3rd Ed.
>
> "The obvious solution for most programmers is to use a library that provides an elegant and efficient platform independent to needed services. Examples are BOOST..."
>       — Bjarne Stroustrup, Abstraction, libraries, and efficiency in C++

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't fit your specific requirements (it's not a business app for a start), I think that [OGRE 3D](http://ogre3d.org) is a great example of an open source C++ project.

Answer (score 1):

V8 javascript engine is said to be very well engineered. http://code.google.com/p/v8/

Google Chrome also has an interesting architecture and high quality code base. http://code.google.com/chromium/

Both are open source, under BSD-like license.