# Open source examples of well designed Python applications

Tags: python, design-patterns, architecture, open-source

Do you know of well designed open source applications that are instructive to analyse?

Of course this question is strictly related to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234276/open-source-examples-of-well-designed-applications), but I am specifically interested in applications written in Python.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190612/where-can-i-get-real-world-examples-of-applications-written-in-python#190883](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190612/where-can-i-get-real-world-examples-of-applications-written-in-python#190883)

Answer (score 3):

[Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) is a python package that is very nicely coded and designed.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Python Standard Library.  It is a great wealth of python code.  I particularly like this.py :)

Seriously though there is good code in the std library.

Answer (score 1):

[Zope](http://www.zope.org/) .

Answer (score 0):

Pyramid is Great !

**[Pyramid - Web Framework](http://www.pylonsproject.org/)**